# ¿Cómo puedo restar el valor que elimino de la columna de la tabla?

Tags: php, javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
function funcEliminarFila() 
{
  $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( "slow", function() { $(this).remove(); } );
}

var sumaTotales = function(){
    var totales = 0;
    $('tr','#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){

     var campo_total = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

     var numero = parseInt(campo_total.val()); totales += isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero; 
   });
  $('#valor_unitario').val(totales);
  $('#suma_1').val(totales);
};

var sumaValores = function(){

    var fila = $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr:last');
    var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)'); 
    var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');
    var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

    campo1.on('change', function(){
      destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
        sumaTotales();
        sumaTotalGeneral();
      });

    campo2.on('change', function(){
      destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
        sumaTotales();
        sumaTotalGeneral();
      }); 
  };

  function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo() 
  {
    $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
    .append
    (
      $('<tr>')
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
        .append
        (
          $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
          )
        )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
        .append
        (
          $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
          )
        )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>')
        .append
        (
          $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]')
          )
        )
      .append
      (
       $('<td>')
       .append
       (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]')
        )
       )
      .append
      (
       $('<td>')
       .append
       (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').prop('readonly', true)
        )
       )
      .append
      (
        $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

        .append
        (
          $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
          )            
        )        
      );
    sumaValores();
  }

<div class="caja6">
  <div class="alcance">
    <h1>DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS</h1> 
  </div>
  <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">

    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
       <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">Nueva</div>
     </label>
     <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
      <tr>
        <th>Detalles De Insumos</th>
        <th>Unidad</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio Unitario</th>
        <th>Valor Total ($)</th>
        <th>OPCION</th>
      </tr>
      <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($detalle_insumo); ++$i) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_insumo[$i][0] ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_unidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_insumo[]" id="cantidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_cantidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" id="precio_unitario_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_precio_unitario_dia[$i][0] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" id="valor_total_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_valor_total[$i][0] ?>" readonly ></td>
        <td class="text-center">

         <div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div>

       </td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
   </table>                 
 </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor podrias editar la pregunta y formatear del código de una forma legible?

Comment: Editas la pregunta y en el editor seleccionas todo el código y le das click a las llaves que están en la barra de herramientas ({}).

Comment: A vos que te parece? Si fueras vos el que va a leer la pregunta cuanto tiempo le dedicarías?

Comment: Esta pregunta es de muy baja calidad y seguramente acabe cerrada si no se edita apropiadamente. Y no solo es cuestión de darle formato al código, también debes añadir una descripción del problema, de lo que hace el código compartido y del resultado que esperas. Lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Monsiens pon la parte del codigo html donde aparece el campo de texto que quieres mantener actualizado al eliminar la fila y sigue los consejos de arriba, para que otro pueda solucionar tus dudas tambien. Saludos. Agregame la parte que falta.

Comment: Es lo mismo que estabas haciendo con el codigo anterior, solamente a hora si elimino una columna se haga la recta correspondiente. saludos

Comment: El código html que digo que falta, es el del campo de costos de insumos, repuestos e insumos, porque el que pusistes solo me indica lo que tienes en la tabla y llega hasta el botón de eliminar.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas es que eso es todo lo que tengo, lo otro es esto

Comment: //DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS
  $detalle_insumo =getdetalleinsumo1($_GET['ids']); 
  $detalle_unidad =getdetalleinsumo2($_GET['ids']);
  $detalle_cantidad =getdetalleinsumo3($_GET['ids']);
  $detalle_precio_unitario_dia =getdetalleinsumo4($_GET['ids']);
  $detalle_valor_total=getdetalleinsumo5($_GET['ids']);

Comment: No entendistes lo que te pedi, deja ver si me explico mejor. En la foto que pones al final de ella hay un campo de texto que tiene valor 10000 y es a donde tienes apuntando una flecha en tu foto, ese campo no lo veo en tu código html porque este solo llega hasta el cierre de la tabla y los div que la encierran. Dime cual es su id pa poder crear una respuesta buena. Edita la pregunta y añade esa información. ;P

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas

Comment: <div class="costo_insumos_repuestos">
  <h2>COSTOS DE INSUMOS, REPUESTOS E INSUMOS</h2><input type="text" name="valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario" class="form-input" placeholder="Valor Unitario" value="<?php echo $power['total_costo_insumos'];?>"  readonly> 
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualiza la primera función que me pusistes en tu pregunta y dejala tal como te pongo esta:

```
function funcEliminarFila() 
{
  //Obtengo el valor del último campo de la fila que se va a eliminar (Valor Total)
  var valorTotalFila = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="text"]:last').val());
  //En caso de que no tenga valor, para evitar errores
  valorTotalFila = isNaN(valorTotalFila)? 0 : valorTotalFila;
  $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut( "slow", function() { $(this).remove(); } );
  //Actualizo el campo donde se almacena todos los valores totales
   var general = $('#valor_unitario').val();
   var valorActual = parseInt(general);
   general.val(valorActual-valorTotalFila);  
}
```

Después me dices si funciona.

Comment: Ramos Diaz, una consulta, si no borrara el ultimo registro, sino el segundo, como seria en ese caso, y disculpa las molestias

Comment: Ramos, disculpa que te moleste pero lograste ver el ejemplo, saludo

Comment: Me imagino que deberia funcionar ya que la acción de actualizar el total viene dada en la función donde eliminas los registros no importa cual fuere.

Comment: asi es @Dariel Ramos Diaz funciona a la perfección, pero a hora tengo un pequeño detalle y te agradeceria mucho si me puedes ayudar. saludos

Comment: Ramos Diaz, te llego la etiquetacion, salidos

Comment: Ramos, eres mi salvacion si me ayudas con eso, de verdad te lo agradeceria mucho, y estaria en deuda contigo. ojala me puedas ayudar y disculpa por tanto molestarte